# Send data from beaglebone black to Host computer

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am trying to send data from BeagleBone to my laptop. My laptop connects with BeagleBone through usb. From my laptop, I can ssh to BeagleBone. In BeagleBone, I will write c code to send data. In my laptop, I will write another code to receive the data. What type of communication to do that? Or any sample code to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are some suggestions on how to make a good question, and get good answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stream the video from camera conneted to beagleboneblcak to your computer via UDP and RTP see the video in the link.
Hope this helps.
[RTP and UDP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6DBR8PSejw)